# How to access only specific item instead of all page with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape some information from a site using Nokogiri.

The site looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <article class="mainarticle">
    <div class="breadcrump">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="boxstyle">
      <h2 style="margin-top:0.1em;">Fahrschulen mit Namen "Hugis Fahrschule AG"</h2>
    </div>
    <section class="leftrightleft  ">
      <header>
        <div class="borderright borderbottom pads">
          <figure class="logoschule">
            <a href="fahrlehrerbilder.php?irat_id=14581" onclick="showGallery('irat_gallery',14581);return false;">
              <img alt="Bilder Hugis Fahrschule AG" width="110" height="110" src="http://www.fahrlehrervergleich.ch/images/lehrer/small/fe1774780ba2d3aaa3e985ee960bf8.jpg">
              <figcaption class="gallerylabel minhide">1 Bild</figcaption>
            </a>
          </figure>
          <div>
            <h3><a href="http://www.fahrlehrervergleich.ch/fahrschule-Hugis-Fahrschule-AG-Z%C3%BCrich-fahrschule-14581.htm" target="_self" title="Hugis Fahrschule AG">Hugis Fahrschule AG</a></h3>
            <h4 style="padding:0;line-height:1.3em;">Thomas  Hugelshofer</h4>
            <span class="biger">Thomas  Hugelshofer</span>
            <p><span>Oerlikon</span><br><span>Schaffhauserstrasse 443</span><br><span>8050</span> <span>Zürich</span></p>
            <p><a href="karte.php?i=14581" target="_blank" onclick="showMap(14581);return false;">Karte</a> &nbsp;<a href="streetview.php?i=14581" target="_blank" onclick="showStreetview(14581);return false;">Streetview</a> &nbsp;</p>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <table class="eintraegemain clearfix">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Homepage:</td>
                <td><a href="fahrlehrervergleich.php?web=14581" target="_blank"><span>www.hugis-fahrschule.ch</span></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>E-Mail:</td>
                <td><a class="" href="kontakt_user.php?kontakt_id=14581" target="_blank" onclick="showEmailSender(14581);return false;">sekretariat@hugis-fahrschule.ch</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Natel:</td>
                <td><span>076 684 11 11</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-section">
          <a class="accordion-section-title  accordeonfarbe-00" href="#accordion-1-14581"><span class="arrow"></span>Preise für Auto: ab 74.-, Auto Automat: ab 74.-, Motorrad: 90...</a>
          <section id="accordion-1-14581" class="secondright accordion-section-content">
            <div class="borderleft pads">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Kategorien</td>
                    <td>Preise CHF</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Auto:</td>
                    <td>ab 74.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Auto&nbsp;Automat:</td>
                    <td>ab 74.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Motorrad:</td>
                    <td>90.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Taxi:</td>
                    <td>74.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Lastwagen:</td>
                    <td>165 .-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Lastwagen&nbsp;C1:</td>
                    <td>165.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Auto&nbsp;Anhänger:</td>
                    <td>112.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>LKW&nbsp;Anhänger:</td>
                    <td>195.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Car:</td>
                    <td>195.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:normal;">Lektionsdauer:</td>
                    <td style="font-weight:normal;">45 Minuten</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Kurse</td>
                    <td>Preise CHF</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Verkehrskunde:</td>
                    <td>150.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Nothelferkurs:</td>
                    <td>120.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Motorrad&nbsp;Grundkurs:</td>
                    <td>160 pro Teil</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Theorie:</td>
                    <td>Nach Anmeldung</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-section">
          <a class="accordion-section-title  accordeonfarbe-00" href="#accordion-2-14581"><span class="arrow"></span>Weitere Informationen: Sprachen: Deutsch, Englisch...</a>
          <section id="accordion-2-14581" class="thirdleft accordion-section-content">
            <div class="borderright pads">
              <table id="sb_14581">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Sprachen: </td>
                    <td>Deutsch, Englisch, Serbisch, Albanisch, Türkisch, Polnisch, Italienisch</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Autotyp:</td>
                    <td>Renauld Megan</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Administration:</td>
                    <td>CHF 110.-  (pauschal)</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Jahrgang:</td>
                    <td>2015</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Ausbildungsjahr:</td>
                    <td>2015</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody></tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <footer class="clearfix">
          <section>
            <div class="bordertop pads" id="sbwl_14581">
              <div class="ratingoutside">
                <ul class="rating">
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li><a href="bewertungen.php?irat=14581" onclick="showBewe(14581);return false;" title="12 Bewertungen anschauen" style="text-decoration:none;">(12)</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="rightbuts"><a class="buttonsmall" href="bewertungen.php?irat=14581" onclick="showBewe(14581);return false;" title="Bewertungen anschauen">Bewertungen anschauen</a>
                <a class="buttonsmall" href="lernen/index.php?bewe_irat=14581">Fahrlehrer bewerten</a>
              </div>
              <p class="clicks minhide clearfix"> 30-Tage-Statistik  : Inserat <span class="num_imp">14069</span> Mal angezeigt, Homepage <span class="num_click">228</span> Mal angeklickt.  (<a href="sponsored.php" target="_blank" onclick="loadSponsored();return false;">sponsored</a>)</p>
            </div>
          </section>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="leftrightleft  ">
      <header>
        <div class="borderright borderbottom pads">
          <div>
            <h3><a href="http://www.fahrlehrervergleich.ch/fahrschule-Hugis-Fahrschule-AG-Adlikon+b.+Regensdorf-fahrschule-13695.htm" target="_self" title="Hugis Fahrschule AG">Hugis Fahrschule AG</a></h3>
            <h4 style="padding:0;line-height:1.3em;">Thomas  Hugelshofer</h4>
            <span class="biger">Thomas  Hugelshofer</span>
            <p><span>8106</span> <span>Adlikon b. Regensdorf</span></p>
          </div>
          <table class="eintraegemain clearfix">
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-section">
          <a class="accordion-section-title  accordeonfarbe-00" href="#accordion-1-13695"><span class="arrow"></span>Preise für Auto: 84.-, Motorrad: 90.-, Taxi: 95.-, Lastwagen:...</a>
          <section id="accordion-1-13695" class="secondright accordion-section-content">
            <div class="borderleft pads">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Kategorien</td>
                    <td>Preise CHF</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Auto:</td>
                    <td>84.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Motorrad:</td>
                    <td>90.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Taxi:</td>
                    <td>95.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Lastwagen:</td>
                    <td>165.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Lastwagen&nbsp;C1:</td>
                    <td>165.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Auto&nbsp;Anhänger:</td>
                    <td>112.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>LKW&nbsp;Anhänger:</td>
                    <td>195.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Car:</td>
                    <td>195.-</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Kurse</td>
                    <td>Preise CHF</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Verkehrskunde:</td>
                    <td>150.-</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Motorrad&nbsp;Grundkurs:</td>
                    <td>160.-</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-section">
          <a class="accordion-section-title  accordeonfarbe-00" href="#accordion-2-13695"><span class="arrow"></span>Weitere Informationen: Sprachen: Deutsch, Englisch...</a>
          <section id="accordion-2-13695" class="thirdleft accordion-section-content">
            <div class="borderright pads">
              <table id="sb_13695">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Sprachen: </td>
                    <td>Deutsch, Englisch, Französisch, Italienisch, Polnisch, Türkisch</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Autotyp:</td>
                    <td>VW, BMW, MAN, SETRA, </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody></tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <footer class="clearfix">
          <section>
            <div class="bordertop pads" id="sbwl_13695">
              <div class="ratingoutside">
                <ul class="rating">
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li class="icon icon-star-two"></li>
                  <li><a href="bewertungen.php?irat=13695" onclick="showBewe(13695);return false;" title="12 Bewertungen anschauen" style="text-decoration:none;">(12)</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="rightbuts"><a class="buttonsmall" href="bewertungen.php?irat=13695" onclick="showBewe(13695);return false;" title="Bewertungen anschauen">Bewertungen anschauen</a>
                <a class="buttonsmall" href="lernen/index.php?bewe_irat=13695">Fahrlehrer bewerten</a>
              </div>
              <p class="clicks minhide clearfix"> 30-Tage-Statistik  : Inserat 307 Mal angezeigt. </p>
            </div>
          </section>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </section>
    <ul class="paginator"></ul>
    <section class="texttabs clearfix">
      <p>
        Fahrschulen in der Schweiz: Fahrschulen und Fahrlehrer für Auto, Motorrad, Lastwagen, Taxi und Boot. Verkehrskunde (VKU), Nothelferkurs, Motorradgrundkurs. Informationen zu Strassenverkehrsamt, Lernfahrausweis, Fahrprüfung, WAB hier im Schweizer Fahrlehrervergleich.                          
      </p>
      <p>
        Der Schweizer Fahrlehrervergleich gibt Auskunft über Fahrschulen und Fahrlehrer, die in folgenden Kategorien unterrichten: Auto, Motorrad, Lastwagen, Taxi und Boot. Ebenfalls werden Angaben über Verkehrtheorie, Motorradgrundkurs, Nothelferkurs und Theorietraining gemacht. Finden Sie eine Auto-, Motorrad- oder Lastwagen-Fahrschule, Informationen zu Ausbildung, Grundkurs, Theoriekurs, Schleuderkurs und Autoprüfung. Fahrschule Fahrschulen Fahrlehrer Zürich Bern Basel Luzern Aargau Schweiz. Der Schweizer Fahrlehrervergleich beinhaltet über 5000 Fahrschulen und Fahrlehrer aus der ganzen Schweiz.                           
      </p>
    </section>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <h2>Fahrlehrer und Fahrschulen finden</h2>
    <section class="filterbox regone boxstyle">
      <h3>Fahrschulen </h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a title="Fahrschule Hugis Fahrschule AG" href="http://www.fahrlehrervergleich.ch/fahrschule-Hugis-Fahrschule-AG-Z%C3%BCrich-fahrschule-14581.htm">Hugis Fahrschule AG</a></li>
        <li><a title="Fahrschule Hugis Fahrschule AG" href="http://www.fahrlehrervergleich.ch/fahrschule-Hugis-Fahrschule-AG-Adlikon+b.+Regensdorf-fahrschule-13695.htm">Hugis Fahrschule AG</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="filterbox regone boxstyle">
      <h3>Sprachauswahl</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a hreflang="de" href="http://www.fahrlehrervergleich.ch" title="Schweizer Fahrlehrervergleich">Schweizer Fahrlehrervergleich</a></li>
        <li><a hreflang="fr" href="http://auto-ecole.comparatif.ch" title="Comparatif d'auto-écoles suisses">Comparatif d'auto-écoles suisses</a></li>
        <li><a hreflang="it" href="http://autoscuola.comparazione.ch" title="Confronto delle autoscuole svizzere">Confronto delle autoscuole svizzere</a></li>
        <li><a hreflang="en" href="http://driving-instructor.fahrlehrervergleich.ch" title="Swiss Driving Instructors">Swiss Driving Instructors</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="filterbox regone boxstyle">
      <h3>Siehe auch...</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.zahnarztvergleich.ch" title="Schweizer Zahnarztvergleich">
          Schweizer Zahnarztvergleich                           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.treuhandvergleich.ch" title="Schweizer Treuhandvergleich">
          Schweizer Treuhandvergleich                           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.anwaltvergleich.ch" title="Schweizer Anwaltvergleich">
          Schweizer Anwaltvergleich                         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.coiffeurvergleich.ch" title="Schweizer Coiffeurvergleich">
          Schweizer Coiffeurvergleich                           </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

My code looks like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
doc.css(".leftrightleft").each do |item|
  title = item.at_css("h3 a").text
  address = item.at_css(".biger+ p , h3+ p")
  address.search('br').each do |n|
    n.replace(" ")
  end
  address = address.text

  puts "-----"
  puts title
  puts "Address:"
  puts address
  puts "Course Types:"

  item.css("table+ table tr+ tr").each do |type_price|
    if type_price.css("td")[0] && type_price.css("td")[1] != nil
      course_type = type_price.css("td")[0].text
      course_type.gsub!(":", "")
      price = type_price.css("td")[1].text
      puts "\t #{course_type}: #{price}"
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I do `item.css("table+ table tr+ tr").each do |type_price|` it's doing it for all items below that one and not only for that item in specific.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use a link to the data. Instead, strip it to the bare minimum, only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem, and include that in your question. Links rot then break, which would result in your question having no input, making it useless to those searching for a similar solution in the future.

Comment: Ok sorry. I updated my question

Comment: The problem is, there's no input data (minimal HTML) to help demonstrate the problem, nor is the code runnable/usable if we want to test it. "[mcve]" is clear about those. You need to help us help you.

Comment: I see. You are right. Hope this is fine now ;)

Comment: The input HTML should be the absolute _minimum_ necessary to demonstrate the problem. Is that the absolute minimum? Writing a good question isn't necessarily easy, but the process of reducing the code to its minimum and making it runnable, and reducing the input often reveals the problem, eliminating the need for asking completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to solve this.

Instead of making the loop like this `item.css("table+ table tr+ tr").each do |type_price|`, that makes it loop to the all page from item until the end of the page, I'm doing it like this `item.at_css("table+ table tbody").css("tr+ tr").each`.

With this solution I'm getting just the first table element and then I loop through the rest of the rows and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look and it seems that Nokogiri is jumbling the elements due to weird markup.

Switching to HTML5 is probably the best bet:

```
require 'nokogumbo'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML5.get(uri)
```

I should really say that libxml is doing the jumbling rather than Nokogiri.

Comment: "I should really say that libxml is doing the jumbling..." Yes. Nokogiri is only the messenger.